# Using CLion as Arduino IDE — Cannot find Libraries

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm having a problem using CLion as Arduino IDE when integrating 3rd-party libraries:

Here is the CMakeList.txt

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(PROJECT_NAME ArduinoIceCream)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD mega)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM4)
set(mega.build.mcu atmega2560)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(C:\\Users\\Xybrek\\Documents\\Arduino\\libraries)

set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_SKETCH ArduinoIceCream.ino)
generate_arduino_firmware(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

Here is the log:

```cpp
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 2016.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Xybrek\ClionProjects\ArduinoIceCream\cmake-build-debug --target upload -- -j 4
-- Generating ArduinoIceCream
-- Using C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy.exe for converting firmware image to hex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Xybrek/ClionProjects/ArduinoIceCream/cmake-build-debug
[ 89%] Built target mega_CORE
Scanning dependencies of target ArduinoIceCream
[ 92%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ArduinoIceCream.dir/ArduinoIceCream_ArduinoIceCream.ino.cpp.obj
C:/Users/Xybrek/ClionProjects/ArduinoIceCream/ArduinoIceCream.ino:22:32: fatal error: BasicStepperDriver.h: No such file or directory
 #include "BasicStepperDriver.h"
                                ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\ArduinoIceCream.dir\build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ArduinoIceCream.dir/ArduinoIceCream_ArduinoIceCream.ino.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/ArduinoIceCream.dir/ArduinoIceCream_ArduinoIceCream.ino.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ArduinoIceCream.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ArduinoIceCream.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/upload.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:211: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/upload.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [upload] Error 2
Makefile:169: recipe for target 'upload' failed
```